# Hovering A Button And Changing Class Of Font Awesome Icon Inside

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, font-awesome

I'm actually boiling furious right now because I've done this exact same thing in a different project and it worked. I have a button I made, it's an `<a>` tag. Inside the `<a>` tag, I have a `<i class="fa">` for an icon. When I hover over the button, I want the color for the `<i>` icon to change. I'm positive the code is correct, just refuses to work. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="workspace">

    <a href="#" class="hlo-btn-round">Search <i class="fa fa-search fa-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Control Icon Color */
.fa-color {
  color: #99999a;
}

/* Control Icon Color on Hover (scripted) */
.fa-hover-color {
  color: #323335;
}


/* Basic Round Button Styling */
.hlo-btn-round, .hlo-btn-round:link, .hlo-btn-round:visited, .hlo-btn-round:active, .hlo-btn-round:focus {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hlo-btn-round:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCD1;
}
```

Script:

```
$('hlo-btn-round').hover(function(){
  $(this).children().switchClass('fa-color', 'fa-hover-color');
}, function(){
  $(this).children().switchClass('fa-hover-color', 'fa-color');
});
```

Comment: do you get an error in console? -- I posted an answer with your code and it seems to work.  BTW, I have never had unreliability issues with jQuery.  Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: No errors in console and if you'd read my entire post, you'd know I'm pretty sure I'm using it correctly. I see no post of yours with an answer.

Comment: I **was** going to answer but with that attitude, I'd rather spend my time helping someone else.  If you **were** using it correctly, you would not be asking for help.  Obviously, something is amiss or you would not be asking here - have a good day!

Comment: Well, that's childish. Calling me names is not going to encourage me to help you

Comment: Its k dude i got it like a few minutes ago, just rewrote everything i had. later bro

Answer (score 2):

No need for the script, should be do-able in pure CSS - see below:

```css
/* Control Icon Color */
.fa-color {
  color: #99999a;
}


/* Basic Round Button Styling */
.hlo-btn-round, .hlo-btn-round:link, .hlo-btn-round:visited, .hlo-btn-round:active, .hlo-btn-round:focus {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 25px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hlo-btn-round:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCD1;
}

.hlo-btn-round:hover .fa {
  color: #323335;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="workspace">

    <a href="#" class="hlo-btn-round">Search <i class="fa fa-search fa-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow that actually worked too, I was expecting it to change all the icons colors not just the one I was hovering. Nice solution! I however did figure out how to script it with like 2 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As @ochi has very well spotted in the comment below your question, your error is a rather common one. You're selecting `$('hlo-btn-round')` which would select any

```
<hlo-btn-round></hlo-btn-round>
```

... elements when, in fact, you probably should be using `$('.hlo-btn-round')`.

You can easily avoid this type of errors by using better coding tools, such as a proper IDE, which would have immediately highlighted the typo for you.

---

**Initial answer:** [.switchClass()](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) (which I've never heard of before - and I'm not exactly a rookie) seems to be part of jQueryUI. Perhaps you loaded it in the other project but not in this one.

jQuery provides the much more popular [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), which can also take a function as a second param to check a condition and return `true` (add class) or `false` (remove class) for that condition.

However, you really don't need `JavaScript` for this. A simple:

```
.parent .child {/* normal state CSS here */}
.parent:hover .child {/* hover state CSS here */}
```

...will do. Or `parent .child:hover{}`, depending on your needs (set `:hover` on the element you want to trigger the effect when hovered).

Comment: I've clearly tagged this question as using jQueryUI, this is closed.

Comment: @KeplerIO It might be closed for you, but please remember you are on [so]. This is open to all future visitors with a similar question/problem. Or is SO a simple: *"fix my code for free, I'll delete the question after, I don't care about the rest"* type of service for you? I hope it's not.